# How can i make an rtf file and tiff file format to be viewed inline in the webbrowser control of c# win forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

How can i make an rtf file and tiff file format to be viewed inline in the webbrowser control of c# win forms?

Whenever i give the path to navigate as the Location of the file it works fine for JPG , PDF but for tiff and docx and rtf a new dialog box appears asking the user to either save it or view it using word. I want those files to be viewed inline with the webbrowser control.

Please anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser cannot natively display TIFFs and Office documents. You *could* upload the file to some service like Google docs, Office live or some 3rd party web service that is capable of rendering documents to HTML.

The other option is to convert the TIFF to JPEG or PNG file, build the HTML with an `img` tag and display it in your webbrowser control. For Word documents you can automate Word to save the file as HTML and then display it in the webbrowser control.